# Why is the Token type for Bool Missing in Go?

Tags: go, token

I have been reviewing the [Go Token Documentation](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.17:src/go/token/token.go) and I have noted that the Go Token type for bool is missing.

Is there a reason why it's not included?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`true` and `false` are  [predeclared identifiers](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Predeclared_identifiers), not reserved words.

At the level of the AST, predeclared identifiers are handled like all other identifiers. Predeclared identifiers are represented by the  [IDENT](https://pkg.go.dev/go/token#IDENT) token type and are scanned by the [scanIdentifier](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/20a71c9a1d7e0d246dfad2c2a2057c954324217d/src/go/scanner/scanner.go#L360) method.

Assuming no shadowing, the identifiers are bound to `true` and `false` in the universal block during name resolution.